# Changing from 3d filter to 2d, first 2d filter shows white face

Tags: 3d, 2d, aframe, 8thwall-xr

Switching to 3D to 2D gives me a white/blank face filter, can't seem to figure out how to avoid that, using `material` to hide the 2d Filter when I want the 3d filter to be shown and remove the `material` property, and change it to material-resource for it to show the 2d Filter

```
  const handlePrev = () => {
    const prevIndex = (currentIndex - 1 + filters.length) % filters.length
    setCurrentIndex(prevIndex)
    const model = document.getElementById('model')

    const faceMeshElement = document.querySelector('xrextras-face-mesh')
    if (filters[prevIndex].type === '2d'){
      // Hide 3D Model
      model.setAttribute('visible', 'false')
      // Change the 2D Model Filter
      faceMeshElement.removeAttribute('material')
      faceMeshElement.setAttribute('material-resource', filters[prevIndex].resource)
    } else {
      // Hide 2D Model
      faceMeshElement.setAttribute('material', 'visible: false;')
      // Show 3D Model
      model.setAttribute('visible', 'true')
    }
  }
```